# What is the difference between `|_| async move {}` and `async move |_| {}`

Tags: rust

Let's consider the following examples:

**main.rs**

```
use futures::executor::block_on;
use futures::future::{FutureExt, TryFutureExt};


async fn fut1() -> Result<String, u32> {
  Ok("ok".to_string())
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    match block_on(fut1().and_then(|x| async move { Ok(format!("{} is \"ok\"", x)) })) {
      Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
      Err(u) => println!("{}", u)
    };
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
futures = "^0.3"
```

I'm asking about the expression `|x| async move {}` instead of `async move |x| {}`. The latter is more obvious, but it runs into the compilation error:

```
error[E0658]: async closures are unstable
```

Then I wonder, what is the difference between `async move || {}` and `|| async move {}`. They both seems to be closures for using the `move` keyword.

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One is the async block (a closure with async block as its body to be precise), while the other is async closure. Per [async/await RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2394-async_await.md):

> `async ||` closures
>
> In addition to functions, async can also be applied to closures. Like an async function, an async closure has a return type of `impl Future<Output = T>`, rather than `T`.

On the other hand:

> `async` blocks
>
> You can create a future directly as an expression using an `async` block. This form is almost equivalent to an immediately-invoked `async` closure:
>
> ```
>  async { /* body */ }
>
>  // is equivalent to
>
>  (async || { /* body */ })()
> ```
>
> except that control-flow constructs like `return`, `break` and `continue` are not allowed within body.

The `move` keyword here is to denote that the async closure and block are to capture ownership of the variables they close over.

And apparently, async closure is still deemed to be unstable. It has [this tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62290).

Comment: So there is no difference in its import right now, isn't it?

Comment: @dronte7 nope, apart from the fact one is unstable.

Comment: they both are immediately turns into a Future with ot without acquiring of some surround variables.
except for being unstable async closure is the same as async block with acquiring of external variables, isn't it?

Comment: @dronte7 they both return a Future *when* being called. As far as capturing variables, they are the same as well. That's what closure stands for, async or not.

Comment: I think capturing variables is quite different in both cases. `async move || ...` will move variables from the enclosing block into the closure, while `|| async move {...}` will move variables from the closure into the async block. if you want to move them from the enclosing block into the async block, I reckon you need to use `move || async move {...}` for now.

Comment: @SvenMarnach at first i was thinking the same but it doesn't work with that way, please [check this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5df35babf7e698fcc0a9baca955bd991). You don't need to add extra move to the plain closure literal which evaluates async block. It should use the reference of `global_string` in the example but it just moves.

Comment: @ÖmerErden This is rather surprising. I'll look into thhis once I've got a bit of time.

Comment: @ÖmerErden I'm very confused now. [See this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39d4788895e68db6c43a893d9e8e8856) which supports @SvenMarnach 's opinion, you need to add `move` before `||`.

Comment: @sify the difference is, in your code you are moving the owner of the reference, not the owner of the vec.

Comment: @ÖmerErden So in my case the variables are copied rather than moved. Then why can't I use a single move to achieve this effect?

Comment: @sify you can, I've just shared an example that points `async move || ...` and `|| async move {...}` both captures from the same scope.

Comment: @ÖmerErden I checked and `async move || ...` works on nightly channel with `async_closure` feature, but `|| async move {...}` doesn't work. Your example uses `|| async move {...}`, you don't need `async_closure` feature and it works on stable channel. But for me `|| async move {...}` doesn't works, the variables `v` and `i` are referenced by the closure but not copied, it must be `move || async move{...}`

Comment: The code within  `async` block does not start till I `await` the future, right?

Comment: This accepted answer is unsatisfying as it fails to address: Why do we have two subtlety different ways to declare async closure-like things?

Answer (score 0):

As to some previous [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156473/what-is-the-difference-between-async-move-and-async-move#comment104566057_59158908) here, there appear to be various ["issues"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/62292) pertaining to the correct syntax.

```rust
(move |x| async move {foo(x)})(x).await
```

should be exactly equivalent to

```rust
(move |x| {async move {foo(x)}})(x).await
```

since a guarded closure apparently cannot be declared `async` outside the guard, and declaring it `async` inside the guard simply opens up another block of code, omitting the braces. The second `move` moves all affected variables -- already moved into the closure -- into the async "safe space" so it would *seem* that all possible protections of `async move` are applied here.