# How to accept an async function as an argument?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, closures, future

I would like to replicate the behavior and ergonomics of taking a closure/function as an argument much like `map` does: `iterator.map(|x| ...)`.

I've noticed that some library code allows passing in async functionality, but this method doesn't allow me to pass in arguments:

```
pub fn spawn<F, T>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<T>
where
    F: Future<Output = T> + Send + 'static,
    T: Send + 'static,
```

```
spawn(async { foo().await });
```

I'm hoping to do one of the following:

```
iterator.map(async |x| {...});
```

```
async fn a(x: _) {}
iterator.map(a)
```

Comment: I think you need a Stream to achieve that, have a look at the crate futures

Comment: @MarioSantini 
https://docs.rs/async-std/1.5.0/async_std/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.any
It does not appear obvious that the functions they're accepting are async, rather the final result appears to be.

Comment: What I ment, was just: if you need to iterate asynchrounously on a collection, you may need a stream instead, that is a feature on which you can iterate.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`async` functions are effectively desugared as returning `impl Future`. Once you know that, it's a matter of combining existing Rust techniques to accept a function / closure, resulting in a function with two generic types:

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn example<F, Fut>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(i32, i32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = bool>,
{
    f(1, 2).await;
}
```

This can also be written as

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn example<Fut>(f: impl FnOnce(i32, i32) -> Fut)
where
    Fut: Future<Output = bool>,
{
    f(1, 2).await;
}
```

- [How do you pass a Rust function as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36390665/155423)
- [What is the concrete type of a future returned from `async fn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58762210/155423)
- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)
- [How can I store an async function in a struct and call it from a struct instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58173711/155423)
- [What is the difference between `|_| async move {}` and `async move |_| {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59156473/155423)

Comment: I Dart if the `.await` is left off it results in `-> Future<Output = Future<Output = bool>>` it is flattened automatically to `Future<Output = bool'>`, so the `.await` is implicit. I haven't found anything so far if Rust does this as well.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not that I'm aware of. Such a thing being implicit feels a little too "loose" to me for Rust, so I'd be surprised if it were added.

Answer (score 9):

The `async |...| expr` closure syntax is available on the nightly channel enabling the feature `async_closure`.

```
#![feature(async_closure)]

use futures::future;
use futures::Future;
use tokio;

pub struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    pub fn map<F, T>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: Fn(i32) -> T,
        T: Future<Output = Result<i32, i32>> + Send + 'static,
    {
        tokio::spawn(f(1));
    }
}

async fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, i32> {
    println!("running foo");
    future::ok::<i32, i32>(x).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let bar = Bar;
    let x = 1;

    bar.map(foo);

    bar.map(async move |x| {
        println!("hello from async closure.");
        future::ok::<i32, i32>(x).await
    });
}
```

See the [2394-async_await RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2394-async_await.md#async--closures) for more detalis

Answer (score 1):

It's too late but I hope this code helps others. In my situation I have some predefined functions which I can not change them (func0, func1, ...) and I need to run them all till the last one in order. If one fails, the whole operation must terminate. So I created an array of functions, then each item will get executed during a loop.

```
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;    

type FuncResult = dyn Future<Output=Result<(), String>>;

async fn apply_funcs(mut start: usize, end: usize) {
   let funcs = [func0];
   let mut result = true;
   while start < end && result {
      result = func_wrapper(funcs[start]).await;
      start += 1;
   }
}

async fn func_wrapper(f: impl FnOnce() -> FuncResult) -> bool {
   match f().await {
      Ok(_) => { println!("ok"); }
      Err(e) => {
         println!("{e}");
         return false;
      }
   }
   true
}

async fn func0() -> Result<(), String> {
   todo!()
}
```

This code fails: ***expected `dyn Future`, found future***

I found 2 ways to solve that:

1: By static dispatching which is by generics:

```
async fn apply_funcs(mut start: usize, end: usize) {
   let funcs = [func0];
   let mut result = true;
   while start < end && result {
      result = func_wrapper(funcs[start]).await;
      start += 1;
   }
}

async fn func_wrapper<Fut>(f: impl FnOnce() -> Fut) -> bool
   where Fut: Future<Output=Result<(), String>> {
   match f().await {
      Ok(_) => { println!("ok"); }
      Err(e) => {
         println!("{e}");
         return false;
      }
   }
   true
}

async fn func0() -> Result<(), String> {
   todo!()
}
```

2: By dynamic dispatching via defining another closure:

```
type FuncResult = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=Result<(), String>>>>;

async fn apply_funcs(mut start: usize, end: usize) {
   let funcs = [
      || -> FuncResult {
         Box::pin(func0())// no await here
      }
   ];
   let mut result = true;
   while start < end && result {
      result = func_wrapper(funcs[start]).await;
      start += 1;
   }
}

async fn func_wrapper(f: impl FnOnce() -> FuncResult) -> bool {
   match f().await {
      Ok(_) => { println!("ok"); }
      Err(e) => {
         println!("{e}");
         return false;
      }
   }
   true
}

async fn func0() -> Result<(), String> {
   todo!()
}
```