# How do I integrate warp with async libraries?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, closures, rust-warp

Warp has a paradigm like this,

```rust
let hi = warp::path("hello")
    .and(warp::path::param())
    .and(warp::header("user-agent"))
    .map(|param: String, agent: String| {
        format!("Hello {}, whose agent is {}", param, agent)
    });
```

Those filters provide [`.map()`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.map) which allows you call a closure with the extracted value (output from prior filter).

How do I operate within this paradigm if in the above example I want to do something like this,

```
.map(async |param: String, agent: String| {
    foo(&param).await?;
    format!("Hello {}, whose agent is {}", &param, agent)
});
```

When I use async functions in a closure in the filter's `.map`, I get this error,

> error[E0708]: `async` non-`move` closures with parameters are not currently supported

Is there anyway to make `warp` compatible with a library that is already async?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`and_then`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.and_then):

```rust
.and_then(|param: String, agent: String| async move {
    foo(&param).await?;
    Ok(format!("Hello {}, whose agent is {}", &param, agent))
});
```

Note that this is not actually an `async` closure, it is a regular closure that returns a future created by an `async` block. See [What is the difference between `|_| async move {}` and `async move |_| {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156473/what-is-the-difference-between-async-move-and-async-move) for more information.